# xcodebuild test-without-building. How to override test run parameters from command line

Tags: macos, xcodebuild

I'm making macOS unit testing bundle (integration test for server software):

```
xcodebuild -project MyApp.xcodeproj -scheme MyApp.macOS build-for-testing
```

As result, xcodebuild generates **xctest** bundle `MyAppTests.xctest` and **xctestrun** file `MyApp.xctestrun`.

Now I can deploy **xctest** bundle on CI server and execute integration tests (by default targeted to release candidate version of server software).

```
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MyApp.xctestrun
```

Now I want to target another server instance (i.e. from development branch).
For doing this I can provide another **xctestrun** file `MyApp-development.xctestrun` with additional settings under `TestingEnvironmentVariables` key.

```
<key>TestingEnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
   <key>com.myapp.ServerKind</key>
   <string>development</string>
   ...
</dict>
```

Launch on CI server:

```
xcodebuild test-without-building -xctestrun MyApp-development.xctestrun
```

But maintaining several **xctestrun** files is not a good idea. I want to have `default` **xctestrun** file and override it's settings from command line.

Is it possible to pass additional settings (or override existing settings) in **xctestrun** file from command line?

Thank you!

Comment: found a soluion?

Comment: I took default `xctestrun` file generated by xcodebuild and added needed variables into `TestingEnvironmentVariables` section. Then i put modified file into `Copy Bundle Resources` of the test target. On CI server, CI script copies `xctestrun` file from Test Bundle resources folder into temporary folder and performs needed modifications using `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`.

So, before running prebuilt test bundle i'm modifying `xctestrun` file to achieve desired environment variables for test bundle.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try this now.

Comment: if you succeeded with this approach, could you please provide more details how you did that ??

Comment: How do you use the environment variables in your code ??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it solves your purpose, but if we wanted to override something like a User-Defined values in the Build settings of the target, i didn't find a straight forward to alter it while running test using xctestRun. So I tried directly altering the info.plist thats available inside the xctest bundle created with "build-for-testing" option before test execution and things seems to work well.

For eg. I wanted to run the test across different partitions, so i did

`defaults write <plist_file_location> PARTITION B1`

and this seems to do the trick

*Note* : Make sure `<plist_file_location>` is an absolute path. Providing relative path would end up creating an entry in `~/Library/Preferences/Info.plist`